# How can I add policy file to the jar applet which is embedded in html file

Tags: java, security, applet, policyfiles

I have this HTML:

```
<html>
<title>The Hello, World Applet</title>
<hr>
<applet code=javaapplication4.test.class 
        archive="JavaApplication4.jar"
        width=600 height=400>
</applet>
<hr>
</html>
```

And I want to add the following policy file to it:

```
/* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Thu May 09 15:48:03 AST 2013*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

grant {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Because I want to let my applet do `AllPermission` like the desktop application.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your HTML could insert a policy file like that to my machine, it would be an huge security bug.  Fortunately, to the best of my knowledge, it is not possible.

If an applet needs trust, digitally sign it.

Comment: I sign it but the browser doesn't ask me about this and I didn't get the required privileged, what is the problem ?

Comment: *"I sign it but the browser doesn't ask me about this"*  Are you sure it did not cache an old version?  Change a sting or something to check the GUI changes.

Comment: BTW - Why code an applet?  If it is due due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: how can I sign the jar with netbeans

Comment: *"how can I sign the jar with netbeans"*  That is an entirely separate question (but for the lack of an '?').  Since I don't provide support for IDEs, I suggest you ask it as a separate question.